# rm(list=ls()) doesn't seem to make syntactical sense

Tags: r

I'm a long-time programmer in C, assembler, etc.  I have just begun an intro to R (not by choice).  On page 2, I encounter `rm(list=ls())` which works to remove all objects.  Since the `=` seems to be assigning the output of `ls()` to something named `list`, you would think that `rm(list=ls())` would do the same thing, since the name shouldn't matter, or even more, why not just `rm(ls())`?  Neither of those work.  Further, the book says that `ls()` *"lists all of the objects..."*, but the output of `ls()` isn't a `list`, it is a `vector` of character strings, apparently. So, apparently `rm()` takes something formally of type `list`, rather than simply a vector of character strings.  Fine.  But if I separately execute `list=ls()`, that creates a vector named `list`, not a list.  So `list=ls()` followed by `rm(list)` is not the same as `rm(list=ls())`, apparently, in violation of what ought to be transitivity of operations or something.

So, apparently `list=ls()` inside of the `rm()` does not assign anything to something named `list`, apparently it produces something of type `list` to be fed into `rm()`.  But that makes no sense, to write `list=ls()` if the goal is to produce something of type `list` from a vector (the output of `ls()`).

Should I just fall on my sword and realize that I am not going to be able to tolerate learning this language? I'm just too grumpy?  Or, is the rest of R going to make perfect sense and I happened to stumble on some kind of ad-hoc adaptation of calling rm that was cooked up?

Comment: Take a look at [named parameters](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Named_parameters). C/assembler are archaic enough to not have them. R and _many_, _many_ other modern languages do. The [unfortunately] named parameter `list` has nothing to do with the `list` data type. You can find out more about `rm` by doing `help("rm")` at an R console. It also seems you are starting off with the wrong resource/book to learn R from scratch. The [SO R FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) has other resources for learning R that might be more helpful.

Comment: "Too grumpy" would be my vote and this vote is coming from a rather grumpy person. R (and its predecessor S) are rather irregular. If you cannot stomach this particular irregularity you have a lot of snarling ahead of you. (Furthermore you are incorrect about nothing being assigned. The formal parameter really is named "list" (even though it is really a character vector) and inside the function body you can see that its value is concatenated with any names that precede it in the arguments.

Comment: if you want to get even grumpier, check out [the r inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: I have dissed (on Amazon) the formerly famous "R Book" because it conflated lists and vectors too many times for my tastes. It came out in a second edition but I didn't spend the $80 to see if they fixed the errors I pointed out. I do agree with you that the `rm`-function's formals names are misleading. The R Inferno is a good read. I suppose it might make a grumpy person grumpier but its real goal is to ease the transition from procedural languages to the functional approach that R uses.

Comment: Thanks to all.  The named parameter was the issue. I'll probably enjoy your recommended r inferno book because I enjoy wallowing in grumpiness (perk of old age).  If it were me I would just use libraries from places like openCV and Numerical Recipes and continue with c/c++, but since I'm helping someone else, I'll pout and learn R.  And R has lots of functions not easily found elsewhere, I understand. I know I shouldn't have gone right to the boards with my question/complaint so early in the process, and I won't do it again (at least before giving it  chance), thanks for humoring me!